# Too many points have been found in contours detected by Opencv findContours function

Tags: opencv, image-processing, kinect

thanks for paying attention to this question.

I want to detect some moving objects by using Kinect Sensor. The idea is quite simple, which first I will get the difference image between every two frames, and then extract the contours of objects, finally do further processing.

I tried to extract the contours by using Opencv(version 2.4.9) function `findContours`, but here the problem comes. The function can extract about 30 or 40 contours in each loop, but in each contour there are about billions of points contained in the contours. Also, if I want to use some functions like `drawContours` or `minAreaRect`, the program will crash due to memory error.

Here are relative code:

```
    findContours(Black, contours, hierarchy, CV_RETR_TREE, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, 
    Point(0, 0));

//1. If nothing has entered the camera frame, skip
    if(contours.size()==0)
    {
        //cout<<"NoContours ";
        continue;
    }

//2. Only save the maximum contour(index) as the result 
    max_index = 0;
    for (size_t i = 1; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        //cout << " Num of Points： " << contours[i].size() << endl;
        if(contours[max_index].size() < contours[i].size())
        {
            max_index = int(i);
        }
    }

//3. If the maximum contour's size is smaller than 5, regard it as noise
    //cout << contours[max_index].size() << endl;
    if(contours[max_index].size() < 5)
    {
        continue;
    }

//find a smallest RotatedRect to express the contour(error happen)
    minRect = minAreaRect(Mat(contours[max_index]));
    RotatedRect minEllipse = fitEllipse(contours[max_index]);
```

Error will happen when it runs to the last two lines code. The mainly reason I think that the function `findContours` found too many points in every contours, which leads to not enough memory.

I cannot send an image for now, but the function `findContours` found about 4294966890 points in at least 50% of contours (while others are normal)

Could anyone give some idea about this?

Comment: Did you check the hierarchy (image topology) @ openCV Doc ? Give a try with CV_RETR_EXTERNAL.

Comment: Dear sriram: Yes I have tried CV_RETR_EXTERNAL instead, but it does not work. In fact this code can work well if I did not use Kinect to catch every frame directly, but use some images already taken from Kinect at first (which means just doing some processing with these images by same method). In my pre-work, I did not care hierarchy at all, but as you suggest I will take a look at it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Andrey Smorodov's answer is the way to go

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [approxpolydp](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html#approxpolydp) to simplify your contours.